# Check picture from picture box same with picture from resources

Tags: c#, winforms, image

I got problem..

When user click CLEAR PHOTO, my picture box will change picture to picture "no_photo"..

That it`s my code

```
  private void btnClearPhoto_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        picEmp.Image = chuki2_spp.Properties.Resources.no_photo;
    }
```

And when user modify current records. It will check photo is same or not from resources. If same, record will saved as DBNull.Value.

```
if (picEmp.Image == chuki2_spp.Properties.Resources.no_photo)
{
    sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empPicture", DBNull.Value);
}

else
{
    sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empPicture", data);
}
```

After user update record, it still keep old picture. Not change to null value in databases. How can I repair that code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not working because picEmp.Image == chuki2_spp.Properties.Resources.no_photo is not true. You are comparing two different objects despite they are holding "the same" image.

Consider using flag to determine if Image was changed or not.